# Calling Controller From Within a Controller

Tags: angularjs

I have two controller, one using the UI Bootstrap modal. When using flat function ([like](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)) it works, but when I try and add them to my modules it does not work, giving an error: Unknown provider: ModalInstanceCtrlProvider <- ModalInstanceCtrl

What is the correct fashion to do this? Code follows:

```
angular.module( 'fb.controllers', [] ).controller( 'ModalInstanceCtrl', function( $scope, $modalInstance, data ) {
    $scope.data = data;
    $scope.ok = function () { $modalInstance.close(); };
    $scope.cancel = function () { $modalInstance.dismiss(); };
});

angular.module( 'fb.controllers' ).controller( 'shortLinkModal', ['ModalInstanceCtrl', function( $scope, $modal, ModalInstanceCtrl ) {
    $scope.open = function ( url, title ) {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open( {
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
            resolve: { data: function () { return { title: 'Short Link', url: url, bb: '[url=' + url + ']' + title + '[/url]' } } }
        });
    };
}]);
```

**On further investigation, it appears that the controller: ModalInstanceCtrl part is expecting a function.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add your modal controller to module, you need to use string literal, like this

`controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',`

Comment: Thank you sirs. That has fixed it. I will accept when I am permitted later. Off to bed...

Answer (score 1):

Controllers can't be injected into other controllers.

Simply pass the controller name, and the `$modal.open()` method will instantiate it:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open( {
    controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
    ...
});
```